# Time complexity of Loops with If statements

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

If I have a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What will be the time complexity if the time complexity of the // do something code is say, linear.

Comment: The `if` has no effect on the complexity class as its executed in `O(1)` itself and only reduces the executions of `// do something` by half. Constants factor do not play a role if you look at the mathematical definition of big-o, so the `0.5` does not change the fact that this code runs in `O(n * k)` where `k` is the complexity of `// do something`.

Answer (score 3):

When you talk about time complexity you generally talk about worst case scenario, so you consider the condition in `if` is true and then decide complexity.

In the given psuedo code, `do something` is executed half of the times, so `O(n/2) => O(n)` times. So `do something` is executed O(n) times. If `do something` is linear time, then Code snippet is of `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement is performed each iteration and is constant time. Let's assume the guarded code is linear. It will be executed half the time, but this factor of 1/2 falls away due to how the big O notation works. Hence, the total time complexity is quadratic, or `O(n*n)`.